# How to silence the last warning when compiling Android apps?

Tags: android

When programming in eclipse I always appreciate that the compiler "thinks with me" and I thus always enable practically all warnings that the compiler offers. And I then program such, that I don't get any! 
One of the warnings that I enable is that the compiler warns me if it encounters an empty block, since that may indicate a possible programming error or oversight on my side. To silence such a warning I then always to enter a comment, indicating that this block or class is intentionally blank.

With Android apps, however, there is always one warning left and that's in the auto-generated gen/package/path/here/R.java resource file, which reads:

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 *
 * This class was automatically generated by the
 * aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
 * should not be modified by hand.
 */

package foo.bar.someappname;

public final class R {
    ...
    public static final class attr {  /* <<< this empty class creates a compiler warning */
    }
    ...
}
```

The empty class "attr" causes a compiler warning (BTW: almost all identifiers in that class violate standard Java naming conventions, esp. re. the use of capitalization in identifiers, but that's a different story).

I would like to silence that "last" warning as well. Is there a template of this class somewhere, so that I could enter some comment there? Or where could I define some dummy value such that this class is not empty anymore? What is this "attr" class used for, i.e. what data will make their way into this class?

Michael

Comment: Do you have the "Undocumented Empty Block" warning turned on in preferences, errors/warnings?

Comment: yes - I have that pref set and I would prefer to keep it set. Would be nice if the code generator could insert some comment here like /* none */ or /* empty */ or such. That would silence this warning...

Answer (score 2):

attr is resource which stores in the `res/values/attr.xml` file

In attr you can create your own attributes for your xml components (views)

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="myattribute" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

If you have have attr resource and its empty then just delete it

See example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/attrs.html)